# Why do (Neo)Vim Color Schemes not Affect Pmenu, PmenuThumb, CocInfoFloat etc.?

Tags: vim, neovim

This has been bugging me for a while now. Why is it that I have to define colors for the floating/popup (you name it) menu by myself in (Neo)Vim, when there are all these beautiful color schemes.

I have to put a lot of time and effort into defining somewhat readable (not that pink hell) menus, which eventually might or might not match the underlying color scheme, but won't match anymore, once I decide to change the scheme.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Is this https://neovim.io/doc/user/syntax.html => section 13. what you mean?

Comment: The builtin colorscheme is obsolete. Just use gruvbox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neovim inherits its built-in colorschemes from Vim.

Vim's built-in colorschemes are all very old, often predating the completion menu feature, and pretty much unmaintained. They lack *many* things beyond the completion menu and they are generally in a bad shape.

I started [an initiative](https://github.com/vim/colorschemes) to modernise the built-in colorschemes but it will take time. If you feel like giving us a hand…

FWIW, `Pmenu` and `PmenuThumb` are built-in highlight groups so it is legitimate to expect them to be handled by the built-in colorschemes but `CocInfoFloat` is not so it is entirely the responsibility of the third-party plugin that defines it to, ideally, link it to a built-in highlight group.

FWIW2, thid-party colorschemes that don't handle 100% of the built-in highlight groups should be considered broken.

--- EDIT ---

The built-in colorschemes have all been remade since I wrote this answer, with special care for the `Pmenu*` highlight groups. They have probably been pulled-in by Neovim already but I don't know since I don't follow that project.

If you are using one of the built-in colorschemes beside `default` AND `CocInfoFloat` **is** linked to a default highlight group, then it should look better, now.

Original `desert` in a 256c terminal emulator:

[image: Original desert in 256c]

Remade `desert` in a 256c terminal emulator:

[image: Remade desert in a 256c terminal emulator]

The original colorschemes actually inherited a lot (including `pmenu*`) from the `default` colorscheme, which doesn't work like the others, as it is a mix of hardcoded and softcoded values. We are currently looking into it but it will take time. In the mean time, enjoy the remakes *and the new ones*:

[image: zaibatsu]

[image: lunaperche]

[image: quiet]

etc.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. I didn't know that the color scheme situation in such a dire shape.